# How do I find Rf values & length size of paper in chromatography?

Tags: chromatography

> A student is designing an experiment using paper chromatography. From previous results, she knows that the Rf values for two dyes that she wishes to investigate are 0.72 and 0.80.
>
> It is proposed that the dyes be run on the same piece of paper and, for various reasons, that the sports should have a separation of a at least 1cm at the end of the procedure.
>
> What is the minimum height of the chromatography paper that she should use in this experiment?

Can someone correct my working out. I don't know what the correct answer is.

- distance travelled by dye x = $x$
- distance travelled by dye y = $y$
- distance of solvent front = $p$
- $x/p=0.72$ therefore $x = p(0.72)$
- $y/p=0.8$, therefore $y = p(0.8)$
- $y-x=1$, therefore $y=1+x$
- new equation: $1+x=p(0.8)$ where $x=0(0.72)$, if we solve for $p$ we get $12.5$

so the piece of paper should be at-least 12.5 cm long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Delta R_f = 0.08$$
Let the separation distance be $\Delta r$ = 1 cm and let $l$ be the length of the paper in cm.

$$\Delta R_f = \frac{\Delta r\, \mathrm{cm}}{l\, \mathrm{cm}} $$

Solve for $l$, obtain $l$ = 12.5 cm.

Comment: why is the change in rf over 1